# Jenkins pipeline stucked infinity when closure return from class run

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, closures

When I run closure that returned by class in Jenkins pipeline, Jenkins stucked in shell command like below.

[image: infinity running..]

The script is

```
class Device
{
    def context 
    
    public Device(context)
    {
        this.context = context
    }
    
    @NonCPS
    def buildDriver()
    {
        return ({
                    context.stage("Build Driver")
                    {
                        context.script
                        {
                            context.print("111111111111")
                            context.sh("pwd;")
                            context.print("222222222222")
                            context.sh("ls -al")
                            context.print("333333333333")
                        }
                    }
                    
                })
    }
}

dev = new Device(this)

pipeline
{
    agent any
    stages
    {
        stage("main stage")
        {
            steps
            {
                script
                {
                    print("start script")
                    dev.buildDriver().run()
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

I think when finish processing shell command, PC is not back to previous pointer..
Just stay in it..
How can I resolve this issue

Comment: Try passing  `pwd` instead of `pwd;`.

Comment: @MaratC Oh that's typo. my code is already without ';'. And issue remains